# how send Comment at many statut php and jquery

Tags: php, jquery, comments, send, at-command

sorry my English very bad

i want ask how i can send Comment at many statut

this statut in while

```
           <form id="com" name="<?php $row[id_statut] ?>">
            <div>
             <textarea id="comm" name="comm"></textarea>
            </div>
          </form>
```

and this code jquery

```
    $("form#com").submit(function() {
        var thiscom = $(this);    

        $.post("commentaire.php", {
          comm: $('#comm').val(),
          statut: $(thiscom).attr('name')      

        },function(data) {
          if (data=='ok') {
           $('#comm').val("");
          }
        }, "json");
        return false;
    });
```

the problem now he send comment just in first statut 
i don't know why ?! help me :'(

Comment: After first send you set comment empty $('#comm').val(""); are you sure you fill it before you send it again? Otherwise it should works.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want but your question is not very clear... I hope i understand it right.

```
<form id="com">
  <div>
    <input type="hidden" name="statut" value="<?php $row[id_statut] ?>">
    <textarea id="comm" name="comm"></textarea>
  </div>
</form>

$("form#com").submit(function() {
    var thiscom = $(this);    

    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "commentaire.php",
       data: thiscom.serialize(),
       success: function(data) {
           if (data=='ok') {
               $('#comm').val("");
       }
    });
    return false;
});
```